Snowflake flatten JSON column in table
I have a column in a table that I need to flatten. Below is the JSON
[
  {
    "Name": "InputData",
    "Value": "{ \"EventType\" : \"Threshold\", \"SubscriptionId\" : \"12345\", \"BalanceDef\" : \"4\", \"ThresholdNumber\" : \"2\", \"ThresholdActionId\" : \"AI_1234567_8912345_6789_1\", \"ThresholdValue\" : \"4.194304E7\", \"FinalThresholdValue\" : \"0.0\", \"SubNetwork\" : \"1\", \"SubVN\" : \"24\", \"SubSource\" : \"2\", \"SubUid\" : \"1234567\", \"MSISDN\" : \"12345678912\", \"iccid\" : \"1234567890123456789\", \"imsi\" : \"123456789012345\", \"rp_uid\" : \"1234567\", \"rpv_uid\" : \"1234567\", \"srv_uid\" : \"12345\" }"
  },
  {
    "Name": "ocs_workflow",
    "Value": "{\"version\":null,\"statusCode\":200,\"message\":\"Success\",\"isError\":false,\"responseException\":null,\"result\":null}"
  }
]

I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. Any help would be highly appreciated, please.
I tried doing a select name.InputData from ACTION_INSTANCES, but it simply gave me an error it was an invalid identifier.
Below is a little screenshot as well.

